# Help changing a select form field depending on calendar date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery calendar here  http://offline.raileisure.com/

I am trying to get the duration select box to change its values depending on what day is selected..

Now the calendar only lets you choose Monday's or Fridays..

I need the select box to only show the following options..

When Monday (5 Days)
When Friday (3 Days, 7 Days, 14 Days)

I don't know where to start :-(

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this that way :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(e) {
        var date = new Date(e);
        var day = date.getDay(); // 0 = sunday etc...        
        // clean all the options
        $("#duration").empty();
        // if monday
        if (day === 1) {
            // add "5 days" options
            $("#duration").append("<option value='5'>5 days</option>");
        // else if friday
        } else if (day === 5) {
            // add 3 / 7 / 14 days options
            $("#duration").append("<option value='3'>3 days</option>"
                                  + "<option value='7'>7 days</option>"
                                  + "<option value='14'>14 days</option>");
        } else { // else...
        }
    }
});
```

When the user picks a date, if fills the `<select>` according to the selected day.

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jJDRQ/)

Comment: @Sylvain - This is without a doubt the most comprehensive answer i have ever had on SO. WOW!! Thanks Buddy

Comment: @ElGabbu - Now i have changed the date format round and the GetDay command doesn't work.. any ideas ???

Comment: What format are you using now? It doesn't work because the constructor of the Date object expects a particular format to be able to create the Date object.

Comment: @ElGabbu - it works with mm/dd/yy but i need dd/mm/yy :-( its taking the date as teh day number, if that makes sense ?

Comment: yes because as you can see in here http://www.cev.washington.edu/lc/CLWEBCLB/jst/js_datetime.html the Date object expects that format ... you can parse the dateText using an explode by "/" and pass the values separetly.

Answer (score 2):

0Oki

You can fire a function on select of a day. When initializing the datepicker do this:

```
.datepicker({
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
               var aDate = dateText.split("/");
               var date = new Date(aDate[2], aDate[1] - 1, aDate[0]); //The - 1 is because the month is zero based.
               alert(date.getDay());
             }
});
```

You can parse the dataText variable and find out if its a monday or friday ... than populate the drop down accordingly :)

Source : http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect

HTH :)

Comment: @ElGabbu - I am not that fluent with jQuery, it does help but its still a bit of a mystery lol

Comment: i have looked at the source html of the page you posted. There are various places where you initializing the data picker. I would start by trying adding this: onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { alert(dateText); } ... it should alert the date selected when you select it :)

Comment: Correct that alerts me with the date :-)

Comment: excellent stuff i saw it :) ... next we need to parse that date ... with follwing code: var date = new Date(dateText);
alert(date.getDay()); ... it should alert 1 for Monday and 5 for Friday ... try it :)